# Use Serilog in a class library from an external assembly, no dependency injection in the main application

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I am working on a project where the main application (a Windows Forms app) is already available and does not use dependency injection.
This main application instantiates some external components (available in an external class library assembly referenced by the main application) by directly calling their constructor. On the other hand these components use dependency injection to instantiate their further dependencies.
The main application:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var appName = "abc";
    var myExtComp = new MyExtComponent(appName);
    ...
}
```

or

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var appName = "abc";
    var myExtWebComp = new MyExtWebComponent(appName);
    ...
}
```

There are 2 kinds of external components, one is a "regular" external helper component:

```
public MyExtComponent(string appName)
{
    Log.Logger = ConfigureLogger(appName);

    IHostBuilder builder = = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

    builder.UseSerilog();

    InitMyExtCompServices(builder);

    IHost host = builder.Build();
    host.RunAsync();
}

private void InitMyExtCompServices(IHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
            ...
        }
}

public class MyService: IMyService
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<MyService> logger;

    public MyService(ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory = LoggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(LoggerFactory));
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>();
    }
    ...
}
```

and the other one contains some web controllers:

```
public MyExtWebComponent(string appName)
{
    Log.Logger = ConfigureLogger(appName);

    WebApplicationBuilder webBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    IHostBuilder builder = webBuilder.Host;
    builder.UseSerilog();

    InitMyExtWebCompServices(webBuilder);

    var app = webBuilder.Build();
    InitWebServerApplication(app);

    app.RunAsync();
}

private void InitMyExtWebCompServices(WebApplicationBuilder webBuilder)
{
    var webHostBuilder = webBuilder.WebHost;
    webHostBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
    {
        ...
    });

    // Add services to the container
    var services = webBuilder.Services;

    services.AddCors(...);
    ...
    services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(...);
    services.AddControllers();
    ... 
}


private void InitWebServerApplication(WebApplication app)
{
    app.UseCors(...);

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}


[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;

    public MyController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyController>();
    }

    ... 
}
```

In both cases the serilog logger is configured:

```
public ILogger ConfigureLogger(string appName)
{
    var logPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) ??
                  $@"c:\Logs\{appName}";
    var logFileNameFormat =
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_FILE_NAME_FORMAT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) ??
        $@"traces.log";
    var logLevelFileStr =
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG_LEVEL_FILE", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) ?? $"Debug";
    var logLevelFile = LogEventLevel.Debug;
    try
    {
        logLevelFile = (LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogEventLevel), logLevelFileStr);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
    }

    var logFileNameTemplate = $@"{logPath}\{logFileNameFormat}";
    var fileOutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}:: {Level:u3}:: {Message:lj}{NewLine}";
    var consoleOutputTemplate =
        "{Timestamp:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}:: {Level:u3}:: {Message:lj}{Properties}{NewLine}";

    // defining Serilog configs
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.Console(outputTemplate: consoleOutputTemplate, theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Colored))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(
            path: logFileNameTemplate,
            restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug,
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            retainedFileCountLimit: 30,
            shared: true,
            flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
            outputTemplate: fileOutputTemplate
        )) // Wrap any file sinks in an Async sink
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

Everything gets executed fine in the external components, but I cannot get anything logged by serilog. The generated log files for instance have no log entries, although logger.LogDebug() (and so on) are called in the external components.
How must serilog be configured in the above scenario to get the logs from the external assemblies containing the referenced components?

Comment: Maybe you can add `.WriteTo.Async(a => a.Debug(outputTemplate: consoleOutputTemplate)` to check if some logs appear in the Visual Studio Output window.

Comment: Great idea, got it fixed! The logging to file was not configured correctly.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use the serilog logger also in the main (win-forms) application?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you can post a other question.